# Keep specific panel of accordion open

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using basic JS for an accordion/collapsible which works well, except now I want to have one panel within a group open at start.

I then tried using JQueryUI for this since it does keep one panel open to start, but then it does not permit multiple panels open at the same time. I read through [the documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) and I don't see where/if that's configurable.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to either modify the below that I had originally or, alternatively, if I'm missing something with JQueryUI.

```
  <script>
      var acc = document.getElementsByClassName(" ols-accordion");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
          acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
              this.classList.toggle("active");
              var
                  olsPanel = this.nextElementSibling;
              if (olsPanel.style.maxHeight) {
                  olsPanel.style.maxHeight = null;
              } else {
                  olsPanel.style.maxHeight = olsPanel.scrollHeight + "px";
              }
          });
      }
  </script>
```

```
      .ols-accordion {
          background-color: #fff;
          color: #1e1e1e;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding: 18px;
          width: 85%;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
          border-bottom: 0;
          text-align: left;
          font-size: 18px;
          line-height: 24px;
          transition: 0.4s;
      }
```

```
      .olsPanel {
          width: 85%;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          padding: 0 18px;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
          background-color: #fff;
          border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
          border-top: 0;
          max-height: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      }
```

Would I need to first add a class or ID to a panel that I want to stay open and then write something separately that assigns the `maxHeight` to that element equal to the `scrollHeight`? Almost like the inverse of what I have above?

Comment: Use the event.target for the toggle, this will target the exact element you are clicking on and only toggle the class for that element.

Comment: @dalelandry not sure if I understand

Comment: In the eventListener, you pass the event into the function => `function(event)` this will allow you to use the event as the element that is being clicked, `event.target` will be the button that is being pressed. If you post a working snippit I can show you what I mean.

Comment: I have added a working snippit of an example that closely matches an accordion that will toggle only the element clicked using `event.target`. This will keep other accordions open if you do not click that specific accordion again to close it.

Comment: Right, but this is essentially what I had to begin with, no? What I need to do is have one of those open by default.

Comment: Did you look at my answer? They all open when clicked. Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you want. This is why it is always a good habit on SO of adding a running snippit of what you are trying to do, even if it is failing, it gives others a basis to work with.

Comment: I did. I am looking to have one accordion open upon page load.

Comment: I see, you can simply add the class tot he default element you wish to be open when you load the page. I have edited my answer. Are you looking for that to be a random event, as in one random element opens on the page load?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `event.target`, passing the ***event*** into the event listeners function and then using the actual element being pressed to toggle a class to apply CSS to that element.

**EDIT:** If you want one of your elements to be open on the page load, simply add the `show` class to that elements HTML and it will be open when the page loads.

```js
//--> Return a node list of all element with the .acc class selector
const acc = document.querySelectorAll('.acc')

//--> run the event (e) into a function and get the
//--> nextElementSibling and toggle a class using 
//--> classList.toggle()
function showPanel(e) {
  e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show')
  e.target.classList.toggle('btnBG')
}

//--> forEach loop that will iterate over each element within the
//--> node list, assign the variable el, to each matching node within that
//--> node list and then assign an eventListener listening for a click
//--> we run the function that toggles the class on our sibling element
acc.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", showPanel)
})
```

```css
.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: start;
  width: 100%;
}

.acc {
   flex: 0;
   line-height: 1.5rem;
   padding: .5rem;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}
.acc:nth-of-type(1) {
 border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.panel {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: inline-block;
}

.btnBG {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-item">
  <div class="acc btnBG">Section 1</div>
  <div class="panel show">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="acc">Section 2</div>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="acc">Section 3</div>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```